# Get a list of expired certificates in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, certificate

I need to list all certificates, that expired more than week ago. I tried this command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\AuthRoot |
    ? {$_.NotAfter -le ((Get-Date).AddDays(-7))} |
    select Subject, Issuer, NotAfter
```

But I only get one result, which is not correct. There are lots of certificates in this store, that expired more than week ago. Furthermore, I don't get the date of expiry listed in the table. I wonder if `NotAfter` is the correct syntax for the expiration date? When I listed all certificates from the store by `| Format-List`, the date of expiry was stated there as NotAfter and this property is also in the suggested properties list after typing `$_.` I even tried this, with the same result:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\AuthRoot |
    ? {(Get-Date $_.NotAfter) -le ((Get-Date).AddDays(-7))} |
    select Subject, Issuer, NotAfter
```

Comment: This is strange. I got a message, when I tried to post the question, that I can post only once every 90 minutes, but when I tried later it seems, that the original question was posted and now it was replaced by this one...

Comment: (to your comments)If it bugs you, ask on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) instead.

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: Did you mean to only search the AuthRoot or did you want all Cert stores?

Comment: Only the AuthRoot. When I list the whole store without conditions, I get as many results as there are shown in the GUI.

Comment: I just rechecked the results of the command without the `where` condition and found out, that some certificates are indeed not shown.  But I can't find any pattern about which certificates are not displayed by PS